# On Snow Leopard, why is -[<ABImageClient> consumeImageData:forTag:] not being called after [ABPerson beginLoadingImageDataForClient:] is called?

Tags: cocoa, osx-snow-leopard, abaddressbook, abperson

I'm trying to load image date for person entries in the shared `ABAddressBook`.  In particular, I'm calling

```
-[ABPerson beginLoadingImageDataForClient:]
```

and passing as the argument an object which adopts `ABImageClient` and implements

```
-[<ABPersonClient> consumeImageData:forTag:]
```

The approach I'm using works fine on Mountain Lion, but fails on Snow Leopard.  In particular, `-consumeImageData:forTag:` never gets called.

The following sample command line program demonstrates my approach:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>

@interface ImageConsumer : NSObject <ABImageClient>
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *imagesForNumbers;
@end

@implementation ImageConsumer

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.imagesForNumbers = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)consumeImageData:(NSData *)data forTag:(NSInteger)tag
{
    [self.imagesForNumbers setObject:data forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:tag]];
    NSLog(@"%s: loaded data of length %zu for tag %zd", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, data.length, tag);
}

@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSArray *persons = [[ABAddressBook sharedAddressBook] people];
        ImageConsumer *imageConsumer = [[ImageConsumer alloc] init];
        for (ABPerson *person in persons) {
            NSInteger loadingKey = [person beginLoadingImageDataForClient:imageConsumer];
            NSLog(@"requested data person named %@ %@ and received tag %zd", [person valueForProperty:kABFirstNameProperty], [person valueForProperty:kABLastNameProperty], loadingKey);
        }
        [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] run];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Am I misusing the ABAddressBook calls for loading image data for instances of `ABPerson`?  Is this a bug with `ABAddressBook` on Snow Leopard?  If so, is there a work-around?